# Protractor get Selenium address from config

Tags: protractor

Is there a way in my test to get the seleniumAddress being used? eg lets say my protractor.config is like this

```
exports.config = {
 seleniumServerJar: null,
  seleniumSessionId: null,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  webDriverProxy: null,

...
...
}
```

I want to be able to get the value of seleniumAddress.

I have tried `browser.params.seleniumAddress` but I guess that only grabs stuff in the params section of the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a cleaner method, but you can do it this way (I used it in my `beforeAll` block)

```
  browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (val) {
        console.log(val.seleniumAddress);
    });
```

You should be able to replace `seleniumAddress` with any other option used in your config file